# Why doesn't Prometheus increase() function account for counter resets?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

According to the [Prometheus documentation the `increase()` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) should account for resets.

> Breaks in monotonicity (such as counter resets due to target restarts) are automatically adjusted for.

However, I have observed a case that seems to contradict this.

If I look at the lifetime graph of `sum(maf_http_req_time_sum)`, I see it hits a peak of `741` before the counter resets.

[image: 741peak]

After the reset it his a new peak of `87`.

[image: 87]

The total lifetime increase of this counter should be over 800.

However, if I try to find the increase of this counter over the last 7 days  (which is before the counter was created), I only see an increase of 437:

[image]

`sum(increase(maf_http_req_time_sum[7d]))` Should return a value greater than 800.

Is there something wrong with the query `sum(increase(maf_http_req_time_sum[7d]))` ?

**EDIT:**

The only thing I can think of here is that maybe `maf_http_req_time_sum` is not technically a counter. It is the `_sum` component of a histogram I created called `maf_http_req_time`.

I cannot find any documentation on what type of metric `maf_http_req_time_sum` is, and `maf_http_req_time_sum` is not listed at all when I hit the URL at: `/api/v1/targets/metadata`

Comment: Probably this is related to extrapolation used in `increase()` function by Prometheus. See https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746 . BTW, could you try this query on the same dataset with VictoriaMetrics? It uses precise calculations in `increase()` function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) . There is also [increase_pure()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase_pure) function.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Prometheus documentation:

> increase should only be used with counters

See more info [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).

I think the "maf_http_req_time_sum" is part of a histogram metric.

See more info [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram).